# How to convert string to list in Django template

Tags: python, django

I want to convert string to list in django template :

Data :

```
{u'productTitle': u'Gatsby Hard Hair Gel 150g', u'productPrice': 0.0, u'productMRP': 75.0, u'hasVariants': 0, u'productSite': u'http://www.365gorgeous.in/', u'productCategory': u'', u'currency': u'INR', u'productURL': u'http://www.365gorgeous.in/gatsby-hard-hair-gel-300g-1.html', u'productDesc': u'A Water type hair gel with is hard setting and gives hair a firm hold It is non sticky hard setting and smooth to the touch Firm hold with wet look spikes', u'productSubCategory': u'', u'availability': 0, u'image_paths': u'["full/548bc0f93037bd03340e11e8b18de33b414efbca.jpg"]'}
```

I want to extract image paths from the above dict but image paths are in string `u'["full/548bc0f93037bd03340e11e8b18de33b414efbca.jpg"]'` is there is any way i can convert it into `["full/548bc0f93037bd03340e11e8b18de33b414efbca.jpg"]` inside template ... i Know it can be done inside the view but can i do this in template....

Comment: May I ask why it's a string in the first place?

Comment: ... and why you don't want to put the logic in your view where it belongs?

Comment: I agree that this sort of thing shouldn't be handled by the template. If you are storing it as json, there are plenty of packages that will handle serialization and deserialization for you automatically when you access the field. Here's one example: https://github.com/bradjasper/django-jsonfield

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could [write a template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that runs a string through json decode.

```
{% for image_path in data.image_paths|your_custom_json_decode_filter %}
  {{ image_path }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is not a good idea though, Why don't you do this in your view though?

Comment: I think that is not a good way to go as in a future he could have another source which does not format his dict and image_paths like that. He better have to abstract it by using an object or do this job in his view.

But your answer will work as expected.

Comment: Oh my god why? He could write a compiler as a template filter -  should he do it? There is obviously flawed design at work here.

Comment: It is clear that is using some kind of an API here, what if another day he wants to support another one ? He will have to rewrite both template and view. And if he wants to keep a long-term & MVC project it is not a good way to go doing this kind of logic in templates.

Answer (score 0):

A template filter is your best option since there is no built in template tag to evaluate a string. If you want to convert it in the template that's your best option. However it wouldn't make that much sense building a template filter in python when you could just modify your data before sending it to the template. Either way you are going to have to do something in python.
If you plan on using the template filter here is an example:

```
@register.filter # register the template filter with django
def get_string_as_list(value): # Only one argument.
    """Evaluate a string if it contains []"""
    if '[' and ']' in value:
        return eval(value)
```

And then in your template you would want to loop over the key,values in your dictionary and pass the values to you custom template filter as so:

```
{% for image_path in data.image_paths|get_string_as_list %}
  {{ image_path }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is so unsafe... [Eval is really dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: `eval` is only dangerous if you have **untrusted** input. His data is clearly coming from the database, and is a server side image path. He should be safe, and if not, his filter can check validity.

Comment: @notbad.jpeg That is assuming that the data entered into the database was valid. There should be no need for the risk involved by using eval when decoding json is an option.

Comment: Being able to use json instead is a good point, but it's still not dangerous to eval on your own data.